# Discord Bot JS - How do I append a role to a specific discord tag?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im currently programming a bot for my discord and I want a command that my mods can write that appends a mute role to a specific player. Currently they type /mute with the discord tag straight after (for example /muteDanyboy#8473) and the discord tag is saved in a variable called commandsplit (as "Danyboy#8473").
How do I target that discord tag and append the mute role to that user?

I use discord.js to program.
Line 23 is the part im looking to get working, thanks.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const TOKEN = "MyToken"
const PREFIX = "/timeout24"
var bot = new Discord.Client();
const COMMAND = "/mute"

/*Confirms the bot is active */
bot.on("ready", function(){
    console.log("Bot Active");
});

/*Gives new members the "Member" role */
bot.on("guildMemberAdd", function(member) {
    member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Member"))
});

/*The mute command */
bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if(message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(COMMAND)) return;
    var commandsplit = message.content.substring(COMMAND.length).split(" ");

    commandsplit.id.addRole(message.guild.roles.find("name", "Muted"))

})
bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: have a look at [`setRoles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setRoles). Set your users role to 'mute'(or whatever), mute them with [`setMute`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=mute) also [create a role if needed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=setName)

Comment: It would be easier if you ping the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [discord.js documentation for guildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) carefully to use .addRole to set the mute role!

Your method is not working properly cause you have a string of username but **.addRole uses an Map(kind of object)** for the member. So you need to store the member is a variable with the given username. Though you can do that as well but a better method will be to use @ mention and they are parsed as object only.

Firstly make an if statement and check if it's the mute command `if(message.startsWith(${prefix}mute);` (You need to call the prefix from `botconfig.json` or define it in the mail file instead first) then inside the if statement use the below code.

```
let muteuser = message.mentions.members.first();
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find('name',"Muted");
muteuser.addRole(muterole);
```

Please make sure you understand the code and not just copy it.

Let me know if you need help with anything

Comment: There are several methods to do this, this is just what I personally prefer ... You can read the documentation to find and use other methods